# list all folder names in directory - unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop

How can I get a list of all folder using shell script, directory is present in HDFS. Here is what i have tried :

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "  loading folders..."
count=0
for folder in `hdfs dfs -ls -d /user/data/*`
do
if [ -d "$folder" ]
then
count=`expr $count + 1`
echo ${d}
fi
done
echo ${count}
```

This value of count variable is 0 at the end of the program.

Comment: `[ -d "$folder" ]` is a linux shell command which can not be used to test if a HDFS path is a directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ask hdfs if the folder is a directory, not bash.

```
if hdfs dfs -test -d "$folder"; then
```

Answer (score 0):

if ! hdfs dfs -test -d $path_on_hdfs; then

echo "Folder Not Present.Creating it"

hdfs dfs -mkdir -d $path_on_hdfs

else

echo "Already present. Delete and re-create"

hdfs dfs -rmr -skipTrash $path_on_hdfs

fi

The above code will create the folder if it is nor present and will delete the folder if it is present.

Thanks,

Regards,

Dheeraj Rampally.